# Expanding line height when equations have displaystyle fractions

Tags: line-spacing, fractions

In my document, I have got a lot of equations in inline mode, like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod
consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equide\textbf{j} dolores. Quo no falli 
viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per. Ius $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ id vidit
volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos \textbf{tttttttt} conqueste 
consulatu. No mei ferri graeco dicunt, ad cum veri accommodare. Sed at malis omnesque 
delicata, usu et iusto zzril meliore.
\end{document}
```

That renders as expected:

[image: Normal text]

The problem is that, as lots of books do, I want to force lines with that kind of equations (they can have more things than just `\dfrac{...}{...}` or `\displaystyle ... \frac{...}{...}`) to have more line height, so the line height is equal to the other lines, and not forced like in the following image:

[image: Fraction problem]

Then, I want this result, where the "j" and the "t"s they don't "compress" the line height.

[image: What I want]

PS: when I'm saying "so the line height is equal to the other lines" I refer to that:

[image: Same line spacing]

Comment: Typesetting stacked fractions in inline text is not a good practice (the spacing is uneven and looks ugly); the form using a slash is preferred for fractions in in-line math, so `$a/b$` instead of `$\frac{a}/{b}$` or `$\dfrac{a}/{b}$` (the latter is the worst one).

Answer (score 10):

You can add

```
\setlength\lineskip{3pt}
```

to stop the lines bumping so close together but either way the result is really horrible. There is `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle` for a reason. Forcing display style fractions in inline expressions will always lead to pain in the end.

The following shows the effect (I adjusted the text width to bring the j closer to the fraction as in the supplied image, the supplied code apparently breaks the lines in a different place)

The last version shows the requested result with the lines opened up even more to preserve the spacing between the fraction and the j but this is I think the least readable of the paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip2\baselineskip

\advance\textwidth-22pt 
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod
consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equide\textbf{j} dolores. Quo no falli 
viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per. Ius $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ id vidit
volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos \textbf{tttttttt} conqueste 
consulatu. No mei ferri graeco dicunt, ad cum veri accommodare. Sed at malis omnesque 
delicata, usu et iusto zzril meliore.


Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod
consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equide\textbf{j} dolores. Quo no falli 
viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per. Ius $\frac{2}{3}$ id vidit
volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos \textbf{tttttttt} conqueste 
consulatu. No mei ferri graeco dicunt, ad cum veri accommodare. Sed at malis omnesque 
delicata, usu et iusto zzril meliore.




Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod
consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equide\textbf{j} dolores. Quo no falli 
viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per. Ius $\nicefrac{2}{3}$ id vidit
volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos \textbf{tttttttt} conqueste 
consulatu. No mei ferri graeco dicunt, ad cum veri accommodare. Sed at malis omnesque 
delicata, usu et iusto zzril meliore.

\setlength\lineskip{3pt}
Eu sit tincidunt incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod
consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equide\textbf{j} dolores. Quo no falli 
viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per. Ius $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ id vidit
volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos \textbf{tttttttt} conqueste 
consulatu. No mei ferri graeco dicunt, ad cum veri accommodare. Sed at malis omnesque 
delicata, usu et iusto zzril meliore.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why was your answer downvoted? Perhaps you could also suggest using `$2/3$` instead of `$\frac{2}{3}$`?

Comment: Or may be a package like `nicefrac` (with `$\nicefrac{2}{3}$`) or `xfrac`.

Comment: @Manuel included that in my answer